# What's this font used for Astrology & Crystals' logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Astrology & Crystals Logo]

I need to know what font is this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 'astrology' and 'crystals' they used a modified version of [Walkway](http://www.dafont.com/walkway.font?text=astrology+crystals)

[image: Walkway Font]

The ampersand is a different font, looks like something in the [Clemente](http://www.dafont.com/clemente-pd.font?text=&) font family

[image: Clemente Font]